# sccm 2012 r2 msi packages failing with error 0x643(1603)

Tags: sccm

I have a question with sccm 2012 r2 and failed packages. For every package I try to deploy there is the odd one that always returns a generic error message  0x643(1603).

I know that this is a generic msi package message, but something has me confused. When i tried to deploy adobe flash.msi it would download the package, seem to install it but will give an error past due - will be retried.

I have set the time for the package to expire 6 hours ahead of the deployment, so a timeout isn't an issue.

When i looked at the `appenforce.log` on the client machine ( located at `c:\windows\CCM\logs\Appenforce.log`) I found the following in the log

```
[LOG[++++++ App enforcement completed (11 seconds) for App DT "Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" [ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4], Revision: 1, User SID: ] ++++++]LOG]!><time="15:45:20.777+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="29796" file="appprovider.cpp:2448">

[LOG[+++ Starting Install enforcement for App DT "Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" ApplicationDeliveryType - ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4, Revision - 1, ContentPath - C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13, Execution Context - System]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.871+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:1702">

[LOG[    A user is logged on to the system.]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.872+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2083">

[LOG[    Performing detection of app deployment type Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)(ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4, revision 1) for system.]LOG<time="15:49:09.874+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2148">

[LOG[+++ MSI application not discovered [MSI Product Code: {FA944726-00F8-43B5-BB97-33E6FF409C22}, MSI Product version: ]]LOG]!>
<time="15:49:09.875+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="msihandler.cpp:131">

[LOG[    App enforcement environment: 
    Context: Machine
    Command line: msiexec /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q
    Allow user interaction: No
    UI mode: 0
    User token: null
    Session Id: 3
    Content path: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13
    Working directory: ]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.875+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:85">

[LOG[    Prepared working directory: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.876+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:189">
<![LOG[Found executable file msiexec with complete path C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.878+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="executility.cpp:188">

[LOG[    Prepared command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q /qn]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.879+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:338">

[LOG[Valid MSI Package path = C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13\install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.880+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:765">

[LOG[    Advertising MSI package [C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13\install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi] to the system.]LOG]!><time="15:49:09.881+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcommon.cpp:125">

[LOG[    Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q /qn with user context]LOG]!><time="15:49:10.268+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:201">

[LOG[    Working directory C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13]LOG]!><time="15:49:10.269+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:215">

[LOG[    Post install behavior is BasedOnExitCode]LOG]!><time="15:49:10.272+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcommon.cpp:1094">

[LOG[    Waiting for process 27844 to finish.  Timeout = 120 minutes.]LOG]!><time="15:49:10.273+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:1958">

[LOG[    Process 27844 terminated with exitcode: 1603]LOG]!><time="15:49:21.074+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:1967">

[LOG[    Looking for exit code 1603 in exit codes table...]LOG]!><time="15:49:21.075+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:505">

[LOG[    Unmatched exit code (1603) is considered an execution failure.]LOG]!><time="15:49:21.075+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="2" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:591">

[LOG[++++++ App enforcement completed (11 seconds) for App DT "Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" [ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4], Revision: 1, User SID: ] ++++++]LOG]!><time="15:49:21.076+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2448">

[LOG[+++ Starting Install enforcement for App DT "Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" ApplicationDeliveryType - ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4, Revision - 1, ContentPath - C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13, Execution Context - System]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.388+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:1702">

[LOG[    A user is logged on to the system.]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.388+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2083">

[LOG[    Performing detection of app deployment type Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)(ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4, revision 1) for system.]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.391+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2148">

[LOG[+++ MSI application not discovered [MSI Product Code: {FA944726-00F8-43B5-BB97-33E6FF409C22}, MSI Product version: ]]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.391+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="msihandler.cpp:131">

[LOG[    App enforcement environment: 
    Context: Machine
    Command line: msiexec /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q
    Allow user interaction: No
    UI mode: 0
    User token: null
    Session Id: 3
    Content path: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13
    Working directory: ]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.392+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:85">

[LOG[    Prepared working directory: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.393+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:189">

[LOG[Found executable file msiexec with complete path C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.394+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="executility.cpp:188">

[LOG[    Prepared command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q /qn]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.395+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:338">

[LOG[Valid MSI Package path = C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13\install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.395+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcontext.cpp:765">

[LOG[    Advertising MSI package [C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13\install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi] to the system.]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.396+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcommon.cpp:125">

[LOG[    Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi" /q /qn with user context]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.800+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:201">

[LOG[    Working directory C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.801+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:215">

[LOG[    Post install behavior is BasedOnExitCode]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.803+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appcommon.cpp:1094">

[LOG[    Waiting for process 29956 to finish.  Timeout = 120 minutes.]LOG]!><time="15:49:27.805+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:1958">

[LOG[    Process 29956 terminated with exitcode: 1603]LOG]!><time="15:49:38.441+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:1967">

[LOG[    Looking for exit code 1603 in exit codes table...]LOG]!><time="15:49:38.441+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:505">

[LOG[    Unmatched exit code (1603) is considered an execution failure.]LOG]!><time="15:49:38.442+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="2" thread="31144" file="appexcnlib.cpp:591">

[LOG[++++++ App enforcement completed (11 seconds) for App DT "Adobe Flash Player 21 ActiveX - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" [ScopeId_C8F1F365-A3C5-47CB-BD87-DB1E3BCFB76D/DeploymentType_a629d54a-d453-49a1-84c1-0192f983f1e4], Revision: 1, User SID: ] ++++++]LOG]!><time="15:49:38.443+420" date="05-27-2016" component="AppEnforce" context="" type="1" thread="31144" file="appprovider.cpp:2448">
```

In the error codes for the package i have:

```
 0 - success (no reboot)
1707- success (no reboot)
3010 - soft reboot
1641 - hard reboot
1618 - fast retry
```

I guess my main question is why does this package keep failing? This has me scratching my head. I am sorry for the formatting of the log files, I tried to clear it up as best as i could.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure this file exists C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\13\install_flash_player_21_active_x.msi
2. Run the msi from this location to see what error you get. Mine was .net3.5 wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MSI to create an install log (add "/L*v C:\Windows\Temp\flash-install.log" for example to the command line) and check there to see why the msi is failing.

Comment: I tried to add the code you gave me but it just spins on installing and doesn't do anything. I was able to get one package installed, but another failed with the same reasoning. I took screen shots of the log files and highlighted different spots but I cant upload images on stack overflow, at least I'm not entirely sure how. If I need to create a link to the pictures, what is the best way to do so? That way I don't paste a bunch of garbage for the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Hkcu/installer/produits/"active x container" and try again